# Vertical scrolling in Ipad app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

In my app i want to display say 20 images at a time.I have an idea for that like I want to create a Scroll view and inside that i will add image view for all images .also i want to show 5 images in a row then in other row 5 more images and 2 more rows consisting of 5 images each.Initially my scroll view should show the  2 rows first and then i will be able to scroll vertically to see the other rows .Can anyone help me with this.Any source code or demo like this.Any help will be appreciated.

I am able to show images in horizontal scrolling but what i desire is something different ,please help.

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at a GridView for this - that's basically what you describe. Check out [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Comment: i downloaded the sample code for this but i am unable to run this ,and its showing a red color on libAQGridView.a ..y this issue i havent came across this situation yet

Comment: did you just download the master archive? i had no issues what so ever to get it to run - just opened it in xcode4 and ran it.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard UI components, no need for third party stuff. Use a UIScrollView and then EITHER a collection of CALayers (if they don't need to respond to touch events) or UIImageViews if the they do.

See my article as an example of how to lay out multiple items, but instead of adding them to the view directly you will add them to a scrollview (and set the content size accordingly)...[Box Model](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/keeping-things-simple-the-dynamic-box-model/)

Comment: why would you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: The number of classes in that GridView for the end result is crazy! You also then rely on someone else's code for what is in effect a VERY simple task and is handled by the UIKit controls.... Adding complexity by introducing endless third party classes / libraries etc for very little benefit is not a good development approach in my eyes.